# Laravel get data from pivot table many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

[Tables with relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j60GT.jpg)

I want to get the classes for specific notes. Here note id and class id are in a pivot table.

```
Note.php

    public function classes()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(MyClass::class);
        }

MyClass.php

public function notes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Note::class);
    }
```

I am saving the data successfully by

```
$note->classes()->attach($request->class);
```

MyClass Migration

```
Schema::create('my_classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->boolean('isDeleted')->default(false);
            $table->dateTime('deletedAt')->nullable();
        });
```

Notes Migration

```
Schema::create('notes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->boolean('isDeleted')->default(false);
            $table->dateTime('deletedAt')->nullable();
        });
```

my_class_note migration

```
Schema::create('my_class_note', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->foreignId('my_class_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('note_id')->constrained();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Needed help on getting classes for a specific note. One note can have many classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply access it by using the relationship property, there always will be if you have defined a relationship.

```
// returns a collection of classes
$classes = Note::find(1)->classes;
```

In your controller.

```
return view('yourview', ['classes' => $classes]);
```

In your view.

```
@foreach($classes as $class)
    <p>{{$class->name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your question seem a little to straight forward, if i misunderstood it please tell me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got in blade file with

`foreach ($note->classes as $class)
  {!! $class->name !!}
endforeach`

Comment: If it solved the problem please remember to accept it as the answer :)